# Obtain maximum attempt count using SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, extract, sql-server-2000

How to obtain the maximum number of attempts made by the `user_field` to achieve or reach a code from the given set of codes (82,83).

That is if a `user_field` finds the code 82 or 83 for the first time, the number of attempts made by the `user_field` should print and so on..

Table_1 is the actual data table and Table_2 is the expected output table

**Table 1:**

```
User_Field |  code
-------------------
100        | 13
100        | 16
100        | 13
100        | 82
 98        | 52
 35        | 13
 98        | 82
 35        | 83
 35        | 16
 35        | 82
```

and the expected output in **Table_2:**

```
User_field | attempts | first_matchcode_in_the_given_codeset
------------------------------------------------------------
100        | 4        | 82
 98        | 2        | 82
 35        | 2        | 83
```

Comment: If the user fails again after succeeding, should those be counted as well? If not, is there a date or similar column identifying time order of the attempts? Also, what if a user never succeeds? Do we show this user at all?

Comment: StuartLC, once the user succeeds, the number of attempts should print and it should skip the further iteration and start processing the next user_field. There is no time or date to identify. If the user never succeed then the attempts should come as '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS....

```
DECLARE @TABLE1  TABLE
(
    SeqNo INT,User_Field INT,  code INT
)
 INSERT INTO @TABLE1 
 SELECT 1,100        , 13 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,100        , 16 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3,  100        , 13 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4,  100        , 82 UNION ALL
 SELECT 5,   98        , 52 UNION ALL
 SELECT 6,   35        , 13 UNION ALL
 SELECT 7,   98        , 82 UNION ALL
 SELECT 8,   35        , 83 UNION ALL
 SELECT 9   , 35        , 16 UNION ALL
 SELECT 10,  35        , 82 

;WITH CTE AS(
            SELECT User_Field,Code,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY  User_Field  ORDER BY SeqNo) Attempts FROM @TABLE1
            ) 
, CTE2 AS
        (
            SELECT User_Field,Code,Attempts,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY  User_Field  ORDER BY User_Field) Nos FROM CTE WHERE CODE IN (83,82)
        )
SELECT User_Field,Code,Attempts
FROM CTE2 
WHERE  Nos =1
```

I think this will work for sqlserver 2000

```
SELECT T1.User_Field,
       COUNT(T1.SeqNo) Attempts,
       (SELECT CODE FROM @TABLE1 WHERE SeqNo = T2.SeqNo AND User_Field = T1.User_Field) CODE 
FROM 
    @TABLE1 T1 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT User_Field,MIN(SeqNo) SeqNo
        FROM @TABLE1 T1
        WHERE CODE = 83 OR CODE = 82
        GROUP BY User_Field
    ) T2 ON  T2.User_Field = T1.User_Field AND T1.SeqNo <= T2.SeqNo             
GROUP BY T1.User_Field,T2.SeqNo
```

Comment: Try my second idea...for seq server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @t table(User_Field int,code int)
insert into @t values(100,13),(100,16),(100,13),(100,82),(98,52),(35,13)
,(98,82),(35,83),(35,16),(35,82)

select User_Field,count(code),
(select top 1 code from @t b where b.User_Field=a.User_Field order by code desc)
  from @t a
  group by User_Field
  order by User_Field desc
```